# How to sort an array of NSNumbers if the NSNumber was created from a string

Tags: swift

Given the following code, y is not an NSNumber but an NSValue, with the consequence that within sort() a call to intValue will crash.
Whats the solution to sorting an array of NSNumbers where the NSNumber was created from a string?

```
        var theArray: Array<NSNumber> = []
        let x = NSNumber(2067876748)
        let y = NSNumber(nonretainedObject: Int("2056787657"))
        theArray.append(x)
        theArray.append(y)
        theArray.sort { (a:NSNumber, b:NSNumber) -> Bool in
            let aintval = a.intValue
            let binvval = b.intValue
```

Comment: Why are you using `NSNumber` in Swift?

Comment: @Dávid Pásztor Passing the array to an Obj-C API which expects an array of NSNumbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Swift code, you should just stick with Swift types and let Swift bridge to a `NSArray` of `NSNumber` for you:

```swift
var array: [Int] = []

let x = 2067876748
array.append(x)

if let y = Int("2056787657") {
    array.append(y)
}

array.sort()

foo.bar(array) // this is objc method defined below
```

Thus, imagine an Objective-C method like this:

```objectivec
@implementation Foo

- (void)bar:(NSArray *)array {
    NSLog(@"Whole array: %@", array);

    for (long i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
        NSNumber *value = array[i];
        BOOL isNSNumber = [value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]];
        NSLog(@"Item %ld is %@, which %@ a NSNumber.", i, value, isNSNumber ? @"is" : @"is not");
    }
}

@end
```

And that will result in:

```
2021-03-02 12:50:23.284723-0800 MyApp[9473:3742305] Whole array: (
    2056787657,
    2067876748
)
2021-03-02 12:50:23.284913-0800 MyApp[9473:3742305] Item 0 is 2056787657, which is a NSNumber.
2021-03-02 12:50:23.284946-0800 MyApp[9473:3742305] Item 1 is 2067876748, which is a NSNumber.
```

---

Ironically, if the Objective-C code is using lightweight generics, you will simply need to be explicit regarding the bridging. E.g. consider:

```objectivec
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Foo : NSObject

- (void)bar:(NSArray <NSNumber *> *)array;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Then you need to be explicit when you call it from Swift:

```swift
let array: [Int] = ...

foo.bar(array as [NSNumber])
```

---

But the moral of the story is that one generally should not use `NS` types in Swift code unless absolutely necessary. E.g. if the arrays were huge or you needed `NSMutableArray` or something exceptional like that, then you might go ahead and use `NS`. But do not prematurely complicate your Swift code for the sake of some Objective-C library/class when it does this bridging so gracefully for us.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to initialise `NSNumber`s from `Int` just to pass them to Obj-C. Swift numeric types are bridged to `NSNumber`, so you can simply cast them using the type casting operator.

```
let intArray = [2067876748, Int("2056787657")].compactMap { $0 }
let nsNumberArray = intArray as Array<NSNumber>
```